# How do you say "Layer" in Chinese? As in photoshop layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm setting up graphic designs that will be printed in mainland China. Some layers of the image are just there to show print instructions, and should never be printed.

What's Chinese for "Layer" as in Photoshop layer?

Google translate thinks the translation of "Do not print this layer" is:
不打印這一層

But we all know it often misses shades of meaning.

Edited to specify: The instructions include cut lines. So as handy as the Photoshop "Notes" feature is, it's not the tool for the job here. The printer has specifically requested that the print instructions go in a separate layer.

Comment: What kind of print instructions? Cut/fold guides?

Comment: Do you have to send the layer in the document or can you remove it before sending to the printer?

Comment: Aye, it's cut guides. And the printer specifically asked for them as a non-printing layer in the document.

Comment: aaah, just saw this comment about them being cut guides, spend 5 minutes editing the questions for nothing... arghhhh! :P

Comment: you should specify that in the question

Comment: for that I would create 2 files just to be sure, one with the cut guides layer, and one ready for print[and off course name the files : NOTforPRINTjustCUTguides.psd... :P ]

Comment: or try the chinese stack exchange...maybe you get lucky there: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that the Chinese word for "layer" might not be the appropriate word for what a Photoshop layer is in Chinese. As an example of what I mean, AFAIK in Japanese, the "file" menu item is "fairu", but this is not the Japanese word for [paper file, file cabinet metaphor], but rather a phoneticization of the English word. Chinese is different of course, but you need to ask someone who knows.

Comment: Horatio: That's exactly the point.

Comment: I was going to migrate this to chinese.SE, but there's a reason not to, which the ever-insightful e100 has his finger on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worries me about this, and e100 put his finger on it, is that your printer asks for the cut line(s) on a non-printing layer. Photoshop doesn't do non-printing layers, but Illustrator and InDesign, as well as Acrobat, definitely have that capability.

That tells me they probably aren't expecting a PSD -- at least not for this kind of work. With the printing being done so far away, that would make me more than a bit nervous. So you're right to be cautious, but I think this is the wrong question. Just because *you say* something is non-printing in the Photoshop file doesn't mean their prepress people will pay any attention, or even notice. The safe route is to make an *actual non-printing layer.*

The most straightforward way of doing this that I can think of is to turn off the cut lines layer, save and bring the PSD into Illustrator (just drag the file into an open Illustrator window). Slightly less direct, but much better if you have text or other vector art in your file, is to save a PDF from Photoshop and open *that* in Illustrator.

This new document will have one layer, the PSD/PDF, so create a new layer by clicking on the New Layer icon in the Layers panel. Name it "Cut Line" and *turn off* the "Print" checkbox:

[image: Cut Line layer dialog]

Draw your cut line on this layer, give it a 1 pt stroke, then lock it. Now you have a file with a real non-printing layer. You can Save As a legacy format if your printer specifies it, or as a PDF. In the PDF, the cut line layer won't be visible by default, but it WILL be there, and will be used by prepress.

To make assurance doubly sure, perhaps, you could edit the layer properties of your cut line layer in the PDF, also. This is what the dialog looks like in Acrobat:

[image: Cut Line layer in Acrobat]

Note that the Visibility has been changed to "Always Visible" and the Print to "Never Prints." As a caveat, I must tell you that I have never, ever had to do this step, but I also have always been in very good communication with my print provider's prepress department.

Comment: In addition to this, if he were to specify a unique spot color for notes and cut lines, and set that color to overprint (no trap), he would have extra insurance against printing, especially if he is paying for 4 color process (i.e. not paying for extra inks), and the printer is aware that such instructions exist.

Comment: @horatio , yeah, he could say something like : DO NOT PRINT NOTHING THAT IS BRIGHT GREEN #123456(hashtag for the color or like u said a unique spot color). and he could make all the instructions cut line bla bla in bright green on a separate layer... good thinking

Comment: +1 for the non printing layer stuff(options of layer in Illustrator) and the stuff in acrobat is neat, but i never really use acrobat, only as a pdf viewer...good to know though, im sure I'll need it at some point :)

Comment: This should work. They do indeed want a PDF at the end, and most of the files get passed through Illustrator on the way there, so this isn't even going far out of the way.

Comment: @baudot "Safety First" is a good motto when stuff is going to press. Especially if it's a long job in a print shop far, far away. :)

Comment: @FlaviusFrantz If you do a lot of print work, you should definitely get familiar with Acrobat's ink management and prepress features. They can be life savers.

Answer (score 2):

Since Photoshop Cs3 there is a neat tool called **Note tool.** 
The problem is that it is hidden behind the eyedropper tool so nobody really knows about it. Use that for any instructions and dont create layers with text as instructions cause they might get printed...it happens.

As for the layers word in chinese... you don't really need it, under the note tool there is the numbers tool, you can "number" the elements you want to specify instructions for.

Play around! Have fun! Look at the screenshot bellow to see what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: The Note tool in CS3 is a standalone tool-group with shortcut key N.  It got moved to the I toolgroup in CS4...

Comment: Thanks for brining this up. As we've discussed in the comments for the main question, cut lines are part of the instructions, so notes alone won't "cut it". But as a relative newcomer to the Adobe suite, I'm happy you pointed it out.

Answer (score 2):

when i see this, the question has been closed,
but i am actually a Chinese and currently live shanghai,
so i just want to say

**"layer" in Chinese should be**

> 层

**and the layer for photoshop in Chinese should be:**

> 图层

Actually the answer you get from Google translate is quite good enough for anyone in our country to understand!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I would definitely mitigate the issue by separating the print instructions out to a separate document, or separate page in a multipage PDF.

Then the printer doesn't have to worry about layers within the document.

Comment: The printer specifically requested a non-printing layer in the document. I want insurance that they'll actually remember not to print it.

Comment: @baudot "specifically requested a non-printing layer" I think its the kind of layer Alan is talking about in his answer(bellow). its not a normal layer in photshop, I like his "workaround" that is not actually a workaround, i think thats the way to do it...[the workaround is that you need illustrator to do that...]

Answer (score 1):

To simplify and just answer your question[basic mode], I just asked a friend about this, he is chinese and working with photoshop, the word for Photoshop layer in chinese is :

```
                                       层
```

That's it. Good Luck!